# how to manually calculate the memory been used

Tags: c#, memory-management

is there any way of calculate manually the memory that an array is goin to consume.

i am using for languaje C# in a 64 bit OS

let say i have the next array:

```
int number[][]= new int[2][2];
number[0][0]=25;
number[0][1]=60;
....
...
```

so my fist question is, each dimension of the array has the same bit asignation? lets say number[0][0] has a 12 bit asing (i dont now if 12 bits is the right answer) so this will make the first line a 24 bit of memory asing?

how much fisical and virtual memory does each dimension takes?

if i use int, double or string for the array is there any diference of memory to been used?

at the end if i used GC.GetTotalMemory will i recibe the same result of the total of memory been used by array?

Comment: `int number[][]= new int[2][2];` is not valid C#, did you mean `int number[,]= new int[2, 2];`?

Comment: Take a look at Jagged Arrays in some cases they will outperform multidimensional arrays
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Comment: the array metion before is actuali a jagged array this the reazon i write this way, it works better for my program but i am not going to explain the hole deal

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the sizeof function to get how many bytes are allocated to your Type.

```
int number[][] = new int[2][];
for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
{
    number[i] = new int[2];
}

int size = sizeof(int) * number.Length * number[0].Length;
```

Comment: Also, there is definately a difference in memory used by different types. A string is an array of chars (about 1 byte each) and can be very long, an int (about 4 bytes) is not too big but you can use short (about 2 bytes) if you don't need to store large numbers, and a double (about 8 bytes) is twice the size of an int and can be used for storing decimals but you can use floats (about 4 bytes) if you are worried about space.

Comment: .NET uses UTF-16 encoding so `char` is 2 bytes each, not 1.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson thaks for the answer but one more quetion in the int array the 4 bytes is for each dimension? in the example this will mean that the array is 8 bytes long in the first line and a great total of 16 bytes int total?

Comment: the 4 bytes is for each int. To calculate the full size, multiply the size of an int (4 bytes) by how many ints you are allocating (dimension 1 length * dimension 2 length ... * dimension n length). In your case you have a 2D array which is 2 in all direction (2 * 2) for a total length of 4 ints, 4 ints * 4 bytes per int = 16 bytes.